# Why when I make a change in 'X' branch my master branch is changing as well in the same way?

Tags: git, web, branch, brackets

I have a `master` branch:

[image]

Then I make `employee` branch from the `master` and change it a bit:

[image]

And when I swipe between branches, the `master` branch also had been changed:

[image]

I have no clue why it happens.

Any suggestions how to return it back to norm?

Comment: Your images don't seem to show anything; maybe the screen capture went wrong.  Therefore, I can't follow your question.  Please include all relevant information directly in your question as _text_.  If you do include images, keep them brief and to the point.

Comment: @phd thnx, looks much better now

Comment: I only [improved changes](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50949960/revisions) by @nicolás-alarcón-r.

Comment: "swipe between branches..." that doesn't describe an actual git command (like checkout). What tool are you using to work with git? Also, how is [tag:brackets] related?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you make a change in your editor, you only modify the code in your "working directory". When you switch branches, those changes in your "dirty" directory come along for the ride.

Once you commit your changes on a given branch, switching branches will no longer bring those changes over.

Answer (score 1):

When you make a change in your editor, you only modify the code in your "working directory". When you switch branches, those changes in your "dirty" directory come along for the ride.

Once you commit your changes on a given branch, switching branches will no longer bring those changes over.

(*Answer By @Joseph Silber*)

Before your case you have three options to make:

A) Maintain changes in the master branch

```
# Agree 
git add file/path/archive
# Perfom a commit
git commit -m "Message"
```

B) Return branch employee and add changes in this branch

```
# Since the terminal gitbash or the manually form
git checkout employee
# Agree 
git add file/path/archive
# Perfom a commit
git commit -m "Message"
```

C) Discard all change

This step will undo all changes that have not been previously added to a commit. Caution!!.

```
git checkout file/path/archive
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you commit to the "X" branch. After you commit to the "X" branch, no change will take place in the main/master branch. But if you switch the master branch without committing to the "X" branch, changes will also be seen in the master branch.

Comment: But ideally this should work without committing to the X branch. Since we are creating a new branch from the master branch, so why should we commit to the new branch when we already have created a new branch from the master branch